# Recovering Dovecot backup

Tags: dovecot

I'm trying to restore mails from a old Dovecot backup. I'm not sure which format I used back then.

I have a Maildir folder as backup, it also has a "cur" and "new" folder which looks like maildir. But there is als a "mailboxes" folder within the Maildir folder which has a INBOX/dbox-Mail folder. All this folders doesn't contain any mails.

But there is also a Maildir/storage folder which contains many m.XXX (e.g. m.435) files. This files contain some mails I would like to restore.

I pointed Dovecot to the Maildir directory and configured it once to use the Maildir format and once to use the dbox format. In both cases my mail client doesn't show any mails.

Does someone know in which formats the mails are stored and how to make them accessible for a mail client?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like maildir+ format to me.  You might need to rebuild the index after restoring.